# How to make Ubuntu remember forever the password after the first time

Tags: password

Is it possible to make Ubuntu remember the password for any program after the first time it asks. I get asked for the password for Synaptic, for making a usb bootable, for connecting to the wifi network, for opening gparted and even to go to the bathroom.

Is there a way to just tell it to ask once forever or just tell it to not ask (Without going to root account. I want to keep using my own account)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is also the sudo configuration file, where you can allow applications to be started without password-query. How to use it, is described here: http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/man/1.8.0/sudoers.man.html

**Warning:** *Though very unlikely, messing with sudoers configuration could lock you out of your system or open doors for others. Always double check and be sure of what you're doing.*

As a safety precaution you can open a root shell and keep it open until you have tested your changes. Open a shell and type `sudo su`, you will be asked for your password. Your shell is now a root shell. Also you can make a backup of your `/etc/sudoers` file to be able revert changes.

The basic use is you edit it by invoking visudo in shell:

```
sudo select-editor # this is optional. it will allow you to select your default editor in shell
sudo visudo
```

The latter of wich will open your shell default editor with the file. Normal syntax is:

```
username machine=(usernameToRunCommandAs) command1,command2,...
```

as in:

```
confus confusion=(root) NOPASSWD:/sbin/halt,/sbin/reboot/usr/sbin/synaptic   #allows user confus to run "sudo synaptic" as root on confusion without password querry
confus ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/sbin/halt,/sbin/reboot #allows confus to shutdown and reboot as all users on all machines without pw
```

As the `$PATH` variable is user dependent and sudo is not, the full path to the command is needed in sodoers list (note it says '/sbin/halt' not just 'halt'). You can find out the full path using the `whereis` command - as in `whereis halt` which will most likely return '/sbin/halt'.

**Generelly speaking that's bad practise**. You are [asked for a reason](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48243/why-cant-non-admin-users-install-software/48249#48249). Installing software with synaptic ist potentially harmfull. As is tempering with partitions which can lead to an unbootable system and massive data loss. It also makes a hackers job much easier. But you're free to do it on your own risk.

Comment: For the record I know this is bad practice, but this is an interesting guide. I don't tend to be bothered by authentication requests, but if I ever do I will consult this! +1

Comment: Note: `shutdown`(without argument -P) is maintenance mode only! Use `halt` or `poweroff` to turn off the machine.