# How to turn an administrator user account into a standard one?

Tags: privileges

I have two administrator user accounts, and I need one of them to turn the other into a standard account.

How do I do that?

Comment: What release Ubuntu are you using

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/45035/disable-sudo-permission-to-user-from-command-line will remove the user from the admin group and disable sudo privileges.

Comment: I usually have two admin accounts on each of my systems for the emergency case when of them may have login issues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Search for user accounts in System settings , there you will get window like this

[image]

Now select the account you want to change to Standard One, Unlock it from the Upper right button which will ask for password.

Now selecting the Account type Button ( refer image) , you will get option as Standard.
It will again ask for password . Now it is done.

For Doing it through Command Line Refer the [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45035/disable-sudo-permission-to-user-from-command-line) provided by **adempewolff** in the above comment.