# How do I add or delete user accounts?

Tags: gui, users, adduser

How do I add or delete user accounts in Ubuntu?

I know that the "useradd" command *could* be used to do this, but I hear that Ubuntu has some other command-line tool *and* some GUI somewhere, either one of which I could use to make adding, deleting, and otherwise managing user accounts much easier and less error-prone.

(An ideal answer will also mention the standard stuff a sysadmin should do immediately after creating a typical new user account -- using Diceware to generate a new [memorable password](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6095/xkcd-936-short-complex-password-or-long-dictionary-passphrase), etc.).

Comment: see this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/139317/3940

Comment: Just for GUI to add user see this http://askubuntu.com/a/149704/63025

Comment: `adduser` is the preferred Ubuntu command line tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can open the system preferences (top right gear symbol).
There is the user program.
This is a GUI Tool for adding and changing users.

You can also generate a random password:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

As [JPbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/users/54187/jpbuntu) has alluded to, [`adduser`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/adduser.8.html) and [`deluser`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/deluser.8.html) are the recommended ways to add and remove users on an Ubuntu system *from the command line*.

Graphically, you can add and remove users in the [GNOME Control Center](https://askubuntu.com/a/156422/22949). Or you may prefer the `users-admin` utility ("Users and Groups"), which gives you greater configurability. `users-admin` is not present by default--to get it, install the [gnome-admin-tools [image: Install gnome-admin-tools]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-admin-tools) package.