# How to allow the following features to Guest in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, guest-session

I use a Ubuntu 14.04 PC. It has an admin and guest accounts. I am the admin of my PC and my sisters use the Guest account. They complained that they are unable to do some things in the Guest account. I will tell it -

1. They are unable to access the 'Volumes'. Is there any way to make them access the 'Volumes' ?
2. Also the history is removed in Firefox in the Guest account after a system restart. Is it possible to keep the history forever ?

Comment: What do you mean by volumes?

Comment: Why not add a regular user account for the sisters? Methinks it's going to be more suitable for regular users you share the PC with.

Comment: All of a guest's files are deleted when they log out. If they want firefox settings to persist, they can set up [firefox sync](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-set-up-firefox-sync) or, as @mikewhatever suggests, you can create ordinary accounts for them.

Comment: The guest session also has an apparmor profile, so to allow some of the features you wish you would have to re-write the apparmor profile as well. the guest session is intended to be limited an temporary, +1 to creating an unique account for each user.

Comment: @mikewhatever Is it possible to create a regular user account with limited access ? This user shouldn't be able to delete files and add or copy new files.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen How to re-write the apparmor profile...?

Comment: Regular users can create, modify, and delete files in their home directory , but not outside of home or system files and this should be fine. For apparmor see - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor

Comment: @bodhi.zazen How to create a regular user ?

Comment: @Tom Here you go: http://askubuntu.com/questions/156409/how-do-i-add-or-delete-user-accounts

Comment: `sudo adduser <username>`