# Remove sudo privileges from a user (without deleting the user)

Tags: sudo

If you give a user sudo privileges how can I remove the sudo privileges and make the user become just a regular user?

I used:

```
sudo adduser username sudo
```

Now I've changed my mind.

Comment: Take a read through this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/45035/disable-sudo-permission-to-user-from-command-line

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If you're like me, you are just trying to figure out how to take away sudo access from a user. It's easy, just open sudo, and type the following in. Keep in mind that **USERNAME** can be replaced by the profile you are doing this to.
In terminal type:

```
sudo deluser USERNAME sudo
```

**This will only take sudo access away from the profile named USERNAME, and will not delete!**

Comment: How is this suggestion different from [the accepted one](https://askubuntu.com/a/335989/504066)?

Comment: Looks like Plane Guy is surfing on other peoples waves.

Answer (score 134):

Just type

```
sudo deluser username sudo
```

This will remove the user named *username* from the group *sudo*.

Be careful not to remove the real adminuser from the `sudo` group.

Comment: @abu-bua: Please don’t approve changes that add *entirely different* solutions to existing answers (a practice commonly called “piggy-back answer”). Those should be posted as separate answers instead. The appropriate rejection reason is: “This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. *It should have been written as a comment or an answer.*” (emphasis mine)

Comment: deluser: command not found. in centos7.

Comment: @LeiYang, apparently `deluser` is a debian thing - have a look at `man groupmems` .

Answer (score 14):

You can also use `gpasswd`:

```
sudo gpasswd -d username sudo
```

This will remove `username` from group `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 22.04 cloud image none of the above worked. I had to also remove the default ubuntu user from file: /etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-users