# How to prevent poweroff / shutdown / reboot / suspend / hibernate by non-root users in Ubuntu Xenial 16.04?

Tags: permissions, suspend, shutdown, hibernate, reboot

Similar questions have been asked about this here but I tried them to no avail. I suspect what used to work in the past have not been working in the latest versions of Ubuntu. I am using Ubuntu Xenial 16.04.

I have tried the following:

1.

```
pico /etc/polkit-1/50-local.d/disable-shutdown.pkla
```

Then fill the file with:

```
[Disable shutdown/restart etc. for users]
Identity=unix-user:a;unix-group:b;
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.reboot;org.freedesktop.login1.reboot-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.power-off;org.freedesktop.login1.power-off-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.consolekit.system.stop;org.freedesktop.consolekit.system.restart;org.freedesktop.upower.suspend;org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.suspend;org.freedesktop.login1.suspend-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=no
```

2.

```
chmod o-x /sbin/shutdown
chmod o-x /sbin/reboot
```

These methods didn't work for me. I could still reboot the server with a non-root account after entering the password:

```
 sudo reboot
```

**EDIT:**
With xxx's account:

```
sudo -l
```

gives

```
Matching Defaults entries for xxx on scw-415fa7:
    env_reset, mail_badpass,
    secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:
                /usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin\:/snap/bin

User xxx may run the following commands on scw-415fa7:
    (ALL : ALL) ALL
```

.

```
sudo grep xxx /etc/sudoers* -R
```

gives

```
/etc/sudoers:xxx ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Comment: `sudo reboot` runs `reboot` as root. That's the whole point of `sudo`. Why give users sudo privileges if you don't want them to run commands as root?

Comment: Alright. Now I see the problem. Could you also please tell me how to take away sudo privileges from non-root users?

Comment: How did you give it to them in the first place?

Comment: I think this will answer my question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/335987/remove-sudo-privileges-from-a-user-without-deleting-the-user

Comment: Hey...sudo deluser xxx sudo...didn't work. It said:  The user `xxx' is not a member of group `sudo'. I think I added the user with this command: adduser xxx.

Comment: Run `sudo -l` as the xxx user and add the output here, please.

Comment: Matching Defaults entries for xxx on scw-415fa7:
    env_reset, mail_badpass,
    secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin\:/snap/bin

User xxx may run the following commands on scw-415fa7:
    (ALL : ALL) ALL

Comment: I can't read that. Edit your post with the output. Also the output of `sudo grep xxx /etc/sudoers* -R`, where xxx is the username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have solved my problem with this on the root account:

```
visudo
```

Then comment out this line:

```
#xxx ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give access to only root, you can do:

```
chmod 700 /sbin/reboot
chmod 700 /sbin/shutdown
```

Comment: Unfortunately `sudo reboot` executes reboot as root.