# Remove sudo access to user

Tags: sudo

I am currently having a problem with removing sudo access from a user. The user is not in the sudo group but is able to carry out sudo commands and I am not sure how I can restrict the user from carrying out sudo commands. I have tried using the sudoer file but Can't seem to figure it out. Thanks so much for the help !

[image: This is the image of the sudoer file]

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the entire sudoers file as text, as well as the output of `cat /etc/passwd | grep username`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove sudo privileges from a user (without deleting the user)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335987/remove-sudo-privileges-from-a-user-without-deleting-the-user) If not, see my comment above.