# How to disable root privilege for SSH'ed users?

Tags: networking, server, permissions, ssh, sudo

I want to setup a VPS that is is open to a few people for them to execute a program. They will connect via SSH. Is there a way for me to keep them from running root commands (sudo, su)?

I tried installing Openssh-server on my laptop running ubuntu 14.04.3 and tried connection via my phone using my password and even though I had *PermitRootLogin* set to *no*, I was able to run sudo commands.

Comment: Why not just disable `sudo` for the altogether?

Comment: I still want access to *sudo* for myslef.

Comment: Keep it for you, disable for them.

Comment: I am looking for a guide to do that, any recommendations besides HATEthePLOT's (which is great)?

Comment: That depends on *how* you granted them `sudo` access in the first place? Via a group? Via individual entries to `/etc/sudoers`?

Comment: Uhm, I have a freshly installed Ubuntu so whatever the default method is? I apologize.

Comment: Have you created these accounts yet? If not, the default account creation methods don't automatically grant `sudo` access, so no problem there.

Comment: I have not, I did however just add *AllowUsers username* to /etc/ssh/sshd_config so does that count as account creation?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance muru, I will look further into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to check out this [link](https://www.servint.net/university/article/keeping-a-tight-ship-ssh-logins-root-vulnerabilities-and-user-privilege-escalation/).
The point is that `PermitRootLogin` diasbles login via the user `root`. This is a security risk. However, your normal user can always login an then escalate to root (e.g. via sudo). An attacker would need two sets of passwords: your user's and root's password, which makes it harder (given you have sane password policies).

If you want to disable a user from `sudo` you have to take this priviledge from him. However, this woud request you doing it on your laptop you want to connect to. AND FURTHER, this will disable your user to use `sudo` on your laptop -- so careful: you might lock yourself out of the system when your only user is removed. (This [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45035/disable-sudo-permission-to-user-from-command-line) might be helpful)