# How do I turn off all the password prompts?

Tags: password

I've been using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS since release and am trying to figure out a couple things about all of these passwords and key-ring prompts that I've just been living with for a while.

Ever since install it seems that every time I boot up my computer and want to do anything (ie. use the internet, use a internet browser, install something, delete something, pick my nose) I'm always prompted for either a normal password entry or a key-ring password entry.

Is there anyway to turn off all of this "security" and tell my Ubuntu that it can trust what I'm doing and go take a shower?

Comment: The key ring has "remember forever" and "don't ask me again" buttons. You can use them. You should only be asked for passwords when you're installing/removing software or editing system files.

Comment: @barkerto and did it work? if so do not forget to upvote and/or accept a suitable answer ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Open dash, search for `passwords and keys` and open it. You can remove the passwords for the keyring here (in the tab `password`). It -should- ask for a new password -once- after that and not ask it again.

> Is there anyway to turn off all of this "security" and tell my Ubuntu that it can trust what I'm doing and go take a shower?

You can leave the new password for the keyring blank. It will complain it is unsafe to do so. Accept it and it should never bug you again. 
And taking a shower should not depend on Ubuntu passwords!

Comment: Also there is the sudoers file for the shell. See (among other sources) here: http://askubuntu.com/q/43969/17789 and here: http://askubuntu.com/q/48243/17789

Answer (score 13):

You can modify /etc/sudoers and find the line:

```
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

change it to:

```
%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Comment: and it user has been added to `sudo` group using command `sudo usermod -aG sudo USERNAME`, modify the line `%sudo` instead of the line `%admin`

Comment: I did this for both sudo and admin, and I'm still constantly asked for my password... what is going on? Can't we just log in once and *be* the admin? Sick of entering my password every 5 minutes setting up this Ubuntu install...

Comment: /etc/sudoers has been replaced by a collection of files at /etc/sudoers.d.  But I don't knocwhat to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

Go to system group and go to the users and grouping center. Then click "change password" and don't do the first question. Finally click "done".
That is how I did it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 14.04 you have to go to *User Accounts*, click unlock in top right, and then go to your account and change your password.

There is an option for login without password.