# My password has deleted by me. What can I do?

Tags: password

I was looking to not enter my password when I am logging in, so I tried running `sudo visudo` and changed `ALL=(ALL) ALL` to `ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`. Which didn't work. So, I changed it back. Now, my password doesn't work when I try to log in.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/136264/how-do-i-turn-off-all-the-password-prompts?rq=1

Comment: The `/etc/sudoers` file is for granting permissions to use sudo. Can you see if you can still log in at the prompt you get if you press CTRL+ALT+F2?